# How can I get strategy of the Linea-Goerli with the vault address?

Tags: web3js, blockchain, metamask, ethers.js, testnets

Like in mantle, we can get the strategy and the contract
by navigating to the site
[https://explorer.mantle.xyz/address/{}](https://explorer.mantle.xyz/address/%7B%7D)

How can I get the same for the line
I have tried the

https://explorer.goerli.linea.build/